# Can I bring a cheese plane in carry-on?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

can I bring a cheese slicer (aka cheese plane) in my carry-on bag? It's a domestic flight, if it matters.

By cheese plane, I don't mean a grater - It slice cheese into thin slices. I'll look for a link on amazon.

By domestic flight, I mean internal U.S. flights.

Comment: Domestic flight in which country? I mentioned an answer for US.

Comment: Here's a link to the type of slicer I mean: https://www.amazon.com/Wusthof-Cheese-Plane-Gourmet-Black/dp/B0060MCRTY/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1502393258&sr=8-4&keywords=cheese+plane

Comment: I have seen them for sale in the airport at Amsterdam, in the secure area. But I would personally not take one on a flight if I have to bring it through security. (I was in the position of needing it and found an other way to transport it.)

Comment: Within USA, it's TSA, and if it isn't clearly covered by a specific regulation, it's up to the discretion (or bad attitude) of the screener who sees it.  I didn't phrase that well.  If the screener _thinks_ (or can argue) that it is implied by a vague regulation.... I had a screener demand the mustache scissors from my bag to measure their length.  One millimeter under the limit!

Comment: Thank you - this totally answers my question. What a catastrophic ending to the Blogin story. Thanks to all the other responders too. I'd rather not risk losing my super cool norwegian cheese slicer to the whims of a TSA agent!! I'll just mail it later.

Answer (score 6):

I would not because it has that sharp edge alongside the back of it, which could arguably be similar to a knife.

According to [TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/sharp-objects):

> In general, you are prohibited from traveling with sharp objects in
>   your carry-on baggage; please pack these items in your checked
>   baggage.

And the [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0060MCRTY) product you listed describes it as

> Incredibly sharp and easily maintained

This [forum](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-security-issues/378330-cheese-slicer-snafu-smf-checkpoint.html) details how one passenger wasn't able to bring his in his carry-on luggage.